# Is a cassandra session thread safe? (using cpp driver)

Tags: c++, multithreading, cassandra, client

I am developing a multi-threaded application and using Cassandra for the back-end.

Earlier, I created a separate session for each child thread and closed the session before killing the thread after its execution. But then I thought it might be an expensive job so I now designed it like, I have a single session opened at the start of the server and any number of clients can use that session for querying purposes.

**Question:** I just want to know if this is correct, or is there a better way to do this? I know connection pooling is an option but, is that really needed in this scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's certainly thread safe in the Java driver, so I assume the C++ driver is the same.

You are encouraged to only create one session and have all your threads use it so that the driver can efficiently maintain a connection pool to the cluster and process commands from your client threads asynchronously.

If you create multiple sessions on one client machine or keep opening and closing sessions, you would be forcing the driver to keep making and dropping connections to the cluster, which is wasteful of resources.

Quoting [this Datastax blog post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/4-simple-rules-when-using-the-datastax-drivers-for-cassandra) about 4 simple rules when using the DataStax drivers for Cassandra:

> 1. Use one Cluster instance per (physical) cluster (per application
>      lifetime)
> 2. Use at most one Session per keyspace, or use a single
>      Session and explicitely specify the keyspace in your queries
> 3. If you execute a statement more than once, consider using a PreparedStatement
> 4. You can reduce the number of network roundtrips and also have atomic operations by using Batches

Comment: So you mean that connection pooling is done by the driver itself?!

Comment: That's right.  Cassandra is highly asynchronous so a single connection to a node can be used by the driver to have many transactions in flight.  For load balancing the driver opens persistent connections to multiple Cassandra nodes and it's efficient at managing and using the pool of connections.

Answer (score 5):

The C/C++ driver is definitely thread safe at the session and future levels.

> The CassSession object is used for query execution. Internally, a session object also manages a pool of client connections to Cassandra and uses a load balancing policy to distribute requests across those connections. An application should **create a single session** object per keyspace as a session object is designed to be created once, reused, and **shared by multiple threads** within the application.

They actually have a section called **Thread Safety**:

> A **CassSession is designed to be used concurrently from multiple threads. CassFuture is also thread safe**. Other than these exclusions, in general, functions that might modify an object’s state are NOT thread safe. Objects that are immutable (marked ‘const’) can be read safely by multiple threads.

They also have a note about freeing objects. That is not thread safe. So you have to make sure all your threads are done before you free objects:

> NOTE: The object/resource free-ing functions (e.g. cass_cluster_free, cass_session_free, … cass_*_free) cannot be called concurrently on the same instance of an object.

Source:

http://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/